# EF Core 6.0 InvalidOperationException: The object has been removed from the model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Am in the process of upgrading a WebApi from .net5 to .net6.   Am hitting a wall with the following exception related to EF Core 6.0 during the Entity Configuration of a domain entity called "Order" which has a one-to-many relationship to "ChargeItems":

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=The object has been removed from the model.
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ForeignKey.get_Builder()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Navigation.OnAnnotationSet(String name, IConventionAnnotation annotation, IConventionAnnotation oldAnnotation)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ConventionAnnotatable.OnAnnotationSet(String name, Annotation annotation, Annotation oldAnnotation)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AnnotatableBase.SetAnnotation(String name, Annotation annotation, Annotation oldAnnotation)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ConventionAnnotatable.SetAnnotation(String name, Object value, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ConventionAnnotatable.SetOrRemoveAnnotation(String name, Object value, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.PropertyBase.SetPropertyAccessMode(Nullable`1 propertyAccessMode, ConfigurationSource configurationSource) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.PropertyBase.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IMutablePropertyBase.SetPropertyAccessMode(Nullable`1 propertyAccessMode)
> at Eventec.Persistence.Core.Orders.OrderConfiguration.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder`1 builder) in E:\Project\PersisentenceCore\Orders\OrderConfiguration.cs:line 101 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration[TEntity](IEntityTypeConfiguration`1 configuration)

This exception is being hit at the following code:

```
public class OrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("orders").HasKey(r => r.Id);
        // other property config etc

        // Charge Items
        builder.HasMany(p => p.ChargeItems)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey("order_id")
            .HasConstraintName("charge_items_order_id_fk")
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);


    }
}
```

Cant find much by way of troubleshooting help using The Google etc.  Nor anything about breaking changes with EF Core 6 to account for this.  Of course it was working just fine with EF Core 5.x.

Comment: So no changes have been made to order or chargeitem class? Does the foreign key constraint exist in the database? Maybe try duplicating those tables, then removing all existing data from them. Then running the app against those? Might be trying to make a change but being blocked due to existing data constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New version, new bugs/breaking changes.

Please go and fill issue/bug report at EF Core [GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues).

The problematic call is

```cs
.Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

As a workaround, either remove it completely (it should be the default), or configure it with the EF Core 5.0 introduced `Navigation` fluent API:

```cs
builder.HasMany(p => p.ChargeItems)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("order_id")
    .HasConstraintName("charge_items_order_id_fk")
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
//.Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

builder.Navigation(p => p.ChargeItems)
    .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

Comment: Ok got it, thx for the reply.  I filled out a bug report:  https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26611

Comment: I implemented your workaround for all my similarly configured one-to-many properties, and it works like a charm.  Thanks a million.  Wound never have figured that out myself.